# Creating a custom Chronology for arbitrary DatePicker

Tags: java, time, java-time

I have a usecase where I want to be able to have the user specify their own calendar in a UI. To allow for this I would like to create a custom Chronology which specifies all the information about the calendar.
The reason I'm using a Chronology and not a custom class is that I want to be able to have this be compatible with the standard chronologies.

I've taken a look at implementing `Chronology` or extending `AbstractChronoolgy`, however I can not find myself around in those classes and I was unable to find resources regarding this usecase.

These are the things I need to be able to customise for each chronology:

- amounts of hours in a day
- amount and names of days in a week (i.e. monday - sunday in the gregorian calendar with 24h each)
- amount of days in a month and the names of the months (i.e. january - december with 28-31 days in the gregorian calendar)
- amount of months in a year
- amount of years in the next larger scale (100 for centuries in the gregorian calendar, leaving out decades)
- which eras exist, and when they started (b.c and a.d. at the year 0 for the gregorian calendar)

Is that feasible with java's chronology? If yes, how would I go about to approach this? Any advice or links would be appreciated.
I don't need a full implementation of the customisability, just a hint to where I can set these things for a custom calendar/chronology would suffice.

Thanks in Advance
Folling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not entirely. `Chronology` is meant to represent existing calendar systems other than ISO/Gregorian. It assigns a **date** to a system of week, month, year, era. It does not cover **time** within a day. As such, it does not offer you the possibility to provide an alternative number of hours in a day. (You could implement the `TemporalUnit` interface to represent "your hour" as a fraction of a day, though.)

To implement `Chronology`, start by extending `AbstractChronology`. You may need to implement the interface `ChronoLocalDate`, `ChronoLocalDateTime`, `Era`, etc. in the process. Last, you must register your implementation with a `ServiceLoader`; see [the API documentation of Chronology](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/chrono/Chronology.html).

Comment: This is what I found as well - I've resorted to a complete custom implementation of the idea of date and time, with a custom DatePicker UI - as I've noticed that whilst the GUI framework I use does say it supports custom chronologies, however it is severely limited in that sense. Thank you regardless!